# JqGrid Update specific Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hi I am using jqGrid with   datatype: 'jsonstring'

Now I want to update a particular row based on the values in the first column.
What I mean

JqGrid definition

```
 $("#grid").empty().jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'jsonstring',
                    datastr: { rows: outputStr },
                    colNames: ['EmpName', 'Val1', 'Val2'],
                    colModel: [
                               { name: 'EmpName', classes: 'EmpName', index: 'EmpName', width: 100, header: 'Currency' },
                               { name: 'Val1',classes: 'Val1', index: 'Val1', width: 160 },
                               { name: 'Val2', classes: 'Val2',index: 'Val2', width: 50 },
jsonReader: {
                        repeatitems: false
                    },


                    rowNum: 10,
                    pager: '#pager',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    hoverrows: false,
                    caption: ""
                }).navGrid('#pager',
                    { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false }, {}, {}, {},
                    { recreateFilter: true, overlay: true, multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true }
                );
```

Consider my grid data as,

```
    
    Johny 122 3123
    Tom 3123 5856
    Susan 124 434
    Cetra 242 2111
```

This is sample data in the grid. Now there is a function which gets updated data, just the data which is updated not the entire grid data. I mean when there is an update for 'Cetra', I receive update for 'Cetra' only

The js function looks like

```
function getDetailUpdate(key, value)
{
 var data = JSON.parse(value);
                var row = $('#grid tr:contains(' + key + ')'); //here I get I am getting update data for who, e.g. 'Cetra'

                var rowVal = $(row).closest('tr').attr('id');  //Here I get the row id
                for (let i in data) {
                   // Below statement is not working
                    $("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData', row, {  'Val1': data[1], 'Val2': data[0]});

//Below statement works and updates the changes but it is not updating in proper row cell, I have also set class names for the three td, and which value to update(which cell) I am getting in 'i')
                    $(row).closest('tr').children('td.' + i).text(data[i]);
                }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the row Id? The best way is to use this instead of hacking on the htmls. var rowData = $('#my-jqgrid-table').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
rowData.Val1= '12321';
$('#my-jqgrid-table').jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, rowData);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
  var row = $('#grid tr:contains(' + key + ')');
```

I am using

```
   var row = $("td").filter(function () {
                        return $(this).text() == key;
                    }).closest("tr");
```

So this is working fine

Alternate way of doing this, by finding the id of tr, as suggested by @Amete Blessed, is a better approach.

```
var rowId = $(row).closest('tr').attr('id');
var rowData = $('#my-jqgrid-table').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
rowData.Val1= '12321'; 
$('#my-jqgrid-table').jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, rowData)
```

Hope it helps someone