# How do I get a Row with multiple values in Jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Ι am currently looking for a way to get a specific Row in Jqgrid.

I know how to get a specific Row with Key in the following article.
However, the problem is that in the example below telling only filter the Row by one condition.

I would like to extract the Row by specifying three values.

[JqGrid Update specific Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945625/jqgrid-update-specific-rows)

The target columns have already been specified in colModel. So the index and name are specified, so it is possible to narrow down the Row.

So, for example, if the columns are named refNum, refNum2, and refNum3, is it possible to filter by three values instead of one, as shown below?

```
var row = $("td").filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text() == key;
                }).closest("tr");
```

Or

```
var row = $('#grid tr:contains(' + key + ')');
```

could you please let me know?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the build in engine for local manipulation called $.jgrid.from - this is actually modified script of [hugo bonacci](http://hugoware.net:4000/projects/jlinq)

Actually you can do (in case your data is local):

```
var my_data = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
var query = $.jgrid.from(my_data);

var result = query.startsWith('refNum','ref_value').startsWith('refNum2','ref2_val').select();
```

If you find this ok, and want to use other commands you can look into the source or let me know what you exactly need.

Comment: I entered three values and it worked fine.
Thank you very much.